# Let $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ be a prime. Then $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\omega]}{\pi \mathbb{Z}[\omega]}$ has $N(\pi)$ elements

Tags: number-theory, eisenstein-integers

I am currently reading cubic and biquadratic reciprocity from Kenneth Ireland and Michael Rosen's, "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" have a doubt in
[proposition 9.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybq1B.png).

We take three cases to prove the second part of this proposition:
(i) assume $\pi$ is a rational prime congruent to 2 modulo 3,
(ii) assume that $p \equiv1\pmod3$ and $\pi \overline{\pi} = p$ ,
(iii) assume 1- $\omega$ is prime

I am unable to figure out how to begin to prove the third case. Can anyone give me a hint or some idea about how to proceed please?
I also want to prove that the number of elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\omega]}{\pi \mathbb{Z}[\omega]}$ in the first case is not ${{0,1,...,p-1}}$.